# How to use "long" type Color in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save a color of a cell to use it later on, on other cells.
I know VBA supports RGB and has its own Color Index, but if you just save the color you get a "long" type value.

How can this "long" color be used on other cells **without** it having to be converted into RGB? Or is there no way around that?

```vb
temp = "I" & PortsNum 'Number of Cell
sh2.Range(temp).Interior.Color = tempcolors 'Color Value
```

Comment: Color *is* a long. RGB is just a way to name some of the bytes in that long

Comment: Not sure what your confusion is. The result of [`RGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) is indeed a long. You can use that long directly with `Range.Interior.Color` (note that this is very different from `ColorIndex`).

Comment: @BigBen I tried to use the long on the Interior.Color attribute of my second cell, but it just paints it black because the cell doesn't know what color it's when it's just a long.

Comment: What is the specific long value you're using? Works fine for me (e.g. `ActiveCell.Interior.Color =  5287936` paints the cell green)

Comment: My Variable has stored 15773696, a light blue.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Interior.Color = 15773696` paints the active cell light blue for me.

Comment: I've put my code in the Question, could something be wrong with that?

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is wrong with it.

Comment: Use the watches window to see what the value is of both `temp`, `PortsNum` and `tempcolors`

Comment: Thank you very much @JvdV. I Found out my problem was with the switch case i've built. It didn't take the Variables to compare but tought they where text, so tempcolors got resetted right after being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use RGB values in VBA to apply to cells in excel I believe. This might help

```
Dim clrBlue As Long

clrBlue = RGB(0, 0, 255)

Application.union(Range("A2"), Range("B3")).Interior.Color = clrBlue
```

Or you can use a long value:

```
Dim a As Long    
a = ActiveCell.Interior.Color
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = a
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I didn't know if you could even use the Value on it's own.